# Qt replaces release into debug in folder names when building debug

Tags: c++, qt, build, qmake

I have an Qt 5.5.1 project (building with qmake and jom, c++ msvc2012) under windows.
Now lets assume my project is located in folder like this:

```
C:\my-release-project\project.pro
```

Now when I build my project in just that folder in debug mode the linker stores the libraries into:

```
C:\my-debug-project\...
```

I dont know why qmake replaces every release in the `DESTDIR` path name with debug. How can i disable that?

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-491, and should be fixed by a newer version of qmake or passing different options to qmake. If you can't upgrade qmake, you should just not use "debug" and "release" in your path names... They are redundant as you can handle debug vs release builds in your .pro file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But the bug was fixed for version 5.2.0 and I am using 5.5.1. In the code-review section of the bug is stated that the fix is deliberatly left out for DESTDIR. Is there a way to tell qmake where to put the binaries other then DESTDIR?

Comment: My bad dude. I saw that, but didn't think much of it. At least I found the bug report ;) I figured you just somehow managed to get an old version of qmake with a newer Qt framework version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments this behavior is intended by qmake when defining the output directory with `DESTDIR`. See: https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/66221/

> For backwards compatibility the new exclusive build behavior is only
>   enabled for variables named by QMAKE_DIR_REPLACE_SANE, which for Qt
>   itself applies globally to everything but DESTDIR, and for libs and
>   tools also applies to DESTDIR. The reason for leaving out DESTDIR in
>   the general case is because many tests and examples assume the old
>   behavior for DESTDIR.

My solution now is to change my projects and not using `DESTDIR` anymore but using shadowbuilds instead. With `$$shadowed($$PWD)` you can get the build folder. Then you will have to decide by build-type to go the standard release or debug folders.

Comment: Solid and modern solution to your problem. Good job! Shadow builds ftw!